# Error when running print dialog from GTK 3.0

Tags: c, gtk3, xfce

I have a small GTK 3.0 project that throws an error when displaying the print dialog. The offending statement is the following:

```c
gint res = gtk_print_operation_run(operation, GTK_PRINT_OPERATION_ACTION_PRINT_DIALOG, GTK_WINDOW(data_passer->application_window), &error);
```

The error is

```
** (deposit_slip:16703): WARNING **: 18:16:42.872: failed to get find a colord device: The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
```

I'm running the program on the Xfce desktop.

What causes this error?

Comment: Do you have [colord](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/colord) installed and running?

Comment: @AndreLDM That daemon is installed, not sure it's running. Will investigate, and thank you for the hint.